# Как заливать/скачивать exe dll файлы в git?

Tags: git

Git по умолчанию не синхронизирует бинарные файлы.
Как это выключить и синхронизировать все файлы?

Comment: Первая фраза неверна. Двоичные файлы можно хранить в Git как и любые другие. Если ваших двоичных файлов много, рассмотрите возможность применения git-lfs.

Comment: @mymedia Можно по конкретней? Я хочу видеть мой exe файл в репозитории и на другом компьютере. Что нужно для этого сделать?

Comment: `git init; git add ваш_файл.exe; git commit; git push; git clone https://example.org/куда_вы_там_отправили`

Comment: @mymedia а можно один раз прописать, что б каждый раз потом не прописывать каждый exe файл? что б как в гитигноре, но только наоборот?

Comment: Не совсем понял, что вам нужно. Вероятно, вам стоит убедиться, что ни в одном из ваших gitignore нету строки наподобие `*.exe`. Если хочется отменить её действие только для определённых файлов, поместите их имена в gitignore, добавив перед ними восклицательный знак (`!`).

Comment: Роман, а зачем вам хранить экзешники в git? Ваш код их использует или вы таким образом релизите приложение или...?

Answer (score 1):

В файле .gitignore написать

```
!*.exe
!*.dll
!*.pdb
```

Comment: Ответ неверный. Git был создан в экосистеме *nix, где у исполняемых файлов обычно нет расширений. По умолчанию Git версионирует абсолютно все файлы, включая `.exe`, `.avi`, `thumbs.db` и `.DS_Store`, скрытые, системные и какие угодно ещё.

Comment: Если конкретно в вашем проекте эти файлы не добавлялись, значит где-то есть правило игнорирования для этих файлов. Оно может быть на уровне проекта — `.gitignore`, либо на уровне системы. Тогда есть несколько решений: 1) убрать это правило, 2) поверх записать исключение (как вы написали в ответе), 3) добавить файлы с `git add -f`.